# 1334 event ID app pool crashes

Tags: asp.net, iis, event-log, application-pool

when running an asp.net application there are intermittent errors occuring like the one below

currently we have requested for the code but until then if there is a solution available it would be great

any help?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Date:          24-3-2011 11:45:25
Event ID:      1334
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      xxx
Description:
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/WebClient

Process ID: 4808

Exception: System.ArgumentNullException

Message: Value cannot be null.

StackTrace:    at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object obj)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TransactedConnectionPool.TransactionEnded(Transaction transaction, DbConnectionInternal transactedObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TransactionEnded(Transaction transaction, DbConnectionInternal transactedObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CleanupConnectionOnTransactionCompletion(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TransactionCompletedEvent(Object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionCompletedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
   at System.Transactions.InternalTransaction.FireCompletion()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedCommitted.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedBase.ChangeStatePromotedCommitted(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.InternalTransaction.DistributedTransactionOutcome(InternalTransaction tx, TransactionStatus status)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.RealOletxTransaction.FireOutcome(TransactionStatus statusArg)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.OutcomeEnlistment.InvokeOutcomeFunction(TransactionStatus status)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ShimNotificationCallback(Object state, Boolean timeout)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">1334</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-03-24T10:45:25.000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>11414</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>xxxx</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/WebClient

Process ID: 4808

Exception: System.ArgumentNullException

Message: Value cannot be null.

StackTrace:    at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object obj)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TransactedConnectionPool.TransactionEnded(Transaction transaction, DbConnectionInternal transactedObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TransactionEnded(Transaction transaction, DbConnectionInternal transactedObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CleanupConnectionOnTransactionCompletion(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TransactionCompletedEvent(Object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionCompletedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
   at System.Transactions.InternalTransaction.FireCompletion()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedCommitted.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedBase.ChangeStatePromotedCommitted(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.InternalTransaction.DistributedTransactionOutcome(InternalTransaction tx, TransactionStatus status)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.RealOletxTransaction.FireOutcome(TransactionStatus statusArg)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.OutcomeEnlistment.InvokeOutcomeFunction(TransactionStatus status)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ShimNotificationCallback(Object state, Boolean timeout)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object state, Boolean timedOut)</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do anything from outside the program.

The message is clear: **Value cannot be null** , this is ether a bug, ether a bad configuration of your program.

One function is called with null value, and crash.

By the way, pool is not crash, just the page is not working.

Comment: The bug is inside internal `.NET` code, it's not possible to change such a code.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/449469/transactedconnectionpool-bug-in-vista-server-2008-sp2

It's known bug with SP2 - I think the most simple work around is what Polchen wrote:

> Disable connection pooling in the
>   database connection string

Hopefully this string is inside configuration file and not hard coded.